# Can't change contents of variable every loop

Tags: python, list, function, math

I have some problem related to the algorithmic script. I have an array in which there is x in which some equation lies, I change them to another variable and everything seems to be fine, but when I come across a number of the same type, I cannot simply continue the calculation. Help me please.

```
def func():
    try:
        a = int(input('Введите диапозон с(пример: 0):'))
        b = int(input('Введите диапозон до (пример: 100):'))
        x = b // 2
        mas = [x]
        for i in range(b):
            first_q = input(f'Ваше число больше {mas}? (если это ваше угаданное число  то напишите(ты угадал!):')
            if first_q == 'Да' or first_q == 'да':
                a = x
                x_1 = x + (b - x) // 2 #+ random.randint(0,1)
                mas.append(x_1)
                mas.pop(0)
                print(x_1)

            elif i == 2:
                 mas.remove(0)
            
            elif first_q == 'Нет' or first_q == 'нет':
                b = x
                x_1 = x // 2
                mas.append(x_1)
                mas.pop(0)
                a = x_1
                print(x_1)

            elif first_q == 'ты угадал':
                print('ООО,отлично спасибо большое за игру!!')
                break

            else:
                break
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I cannot simply continue the calculation"? What's stopping you? Can you provide an example input that "breaks" the code?

Comment: The content of the variable does not change with each arrival of the loop. That is, the variable remains equal to 5.How can I change a variable to a variable that has already been calculated (which I have in my code)

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure I follow... Since you speak Russian, you could ask at https://ru.stackoverflow.com in Russian. Again, an example of input that breaks the code could help.